# Iteration of checkboxes to pdf c# and itextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, foreach, itext

i have a form with multiple text boxes and need to take the values of these and insert them into a PDF via itextsharp. currently i use an if statement for each like this,

```
If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CheckBox1", "Yes")
    Else
        pdfFormFields.SetField("CheckBox1", "No")
    End If
```

I am looking to do the same thing for all check boxes in the form but would like on function to do it, i have tried a couple of way but cant seem to find one that works.

I can use

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
   if(c is CheckBox)
   {
   // Do stuff here ;]
   }
}
```

to iterate through them but its the checking status and preforming the action im stuck on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming checkbox name are the same in the form and PDF can't you do :

```
foreach(var checkbox in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
   pdfFormFields.SetField(checkbox.Name, checkbox.Checked ? "Yes": "No");
}
```

Comment: Does exactly what i needed it to do! thanks very much!

Comment: So......ive had to change to running a class if i try data.((checkbox.Name, checkbox.Checked ? "Yes": "No");                                                                    it says identifier expected how would i set up the class bool to allow this?